# How to know when a new docker container is created

Tags: linux, docker

What is the most optimal way for a process on a Linux PC to get informed automatically when a new Docker container is created ?

I know it is possible to check the date with Docker Engine API, but there is maybe a better solution, with file watchers or something like that ?

Comment: The Docker API includes a [monitor events](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#tag/System/operation/SystemEvents) call, which various Docker SDKs may support; have you looked into that at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ docker events --filter "type=container" --filter "event=create" --format "{{json .}}" | jq -r
```

will listen all docker events in real time and print only `container create` events like:

```json
{
  "status": "create",
  "id": "0d4f9f...f072c1e305",
  "from": "hello-world",
  "Type": "container",
  "Action": "create",
  "Actor": {
    "ID": "0d4f9f9b8b20...7f072c1e305",
    "Attributes": {
      "desktop.docker.io/wsl-distro": "Debian",
      "image": "hello-world",
      "name": "lucid_engelbart"
    }
  },
  "scope": "local",
  "time": 1667446412,
  "timeNano": 1667446412029074700
}
```

Also, you may set dates:

```
$ docker events --since $(date "+%s" -d "-1 day") --until $(date "+%s") --filter "type=container" --filter "event=create" --format "{{json .}}" | jq -r
```

will print all events for one day.

[Manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/)

Also, it is possible to use `curl` to get info via REST API:

```bash
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --unix-socket /var/run/docker.sock "http://localhost/events?since=$(date "+%s" -d "-1 day")&until=$(date "+%s")&filters=%7B%22event%22%3A%7B%22create%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%7B%22container%22%3Atrue%7D%7D" | jq
```

Docker is listening to Unix socket by default so `--unix-socket` parameter is needed. However, it is possible to connect to Docker via TCP socket, but you have to [change Docker Engine parameters](https://gist.github.com/styblope/dc55e0ad2a9848f2cc3307d4819d819f) (Not sure but probably web socket may be used in this case?).
Also, if you set `until` parameter (CLI and `curl` the same) Docker will print all events `until` date and exit without continuous listening for new ones.

Of course, Docker libraries and SDKs may be used to get same output programmatically, but it depends on programming language, so it is hard to provide exact example

＊pipelined `jq` is not necessary in real usage. I just added it for pretty printing.

<sub><sup>PS. Thanks to @David Maze for the comment. Didn't know about this feature before</sup></sub>

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there is a event system.
The documentation is about a CLI interface, is it possible to be in direct connection with the Docker daemon process, to avoid a clunky system with serialization of command line prints continuously ?
Something like websockets for the web.

Comment: @Grum I updated my answer. Is it answering your ↑ question?

Comment: Yes thanks, I will know use go directly to stream the unix socket and start a function each time.